# html webpack plugin and new lines after injection

Tags: javascript, webpack, ejs, html-webpack-plugin

i am using `webpack` version 4.41.2 in conjunction with [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) version 3.2.0

```sh
$ npm info webpack version
4.41.2

$ npm info html-webpack-plugin version
3.2.0
```

i have created an html template, named `index.ejs` (named it this way [to eliminate any conflicts with `html-loader`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/952#issuecomment-390632293). i am not using `html-loader` plugin).

here is the corresponding `webpack` configuration:

```js
new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  template: "src/index.ejs",
  filename: "index.html",
  inject:   "body"
})
```

after examination of the rendering output, i see that all `<script>` tags are concatenated without any new lines

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors~main.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
```

any idea what am i doing wrong or how can i fix it to have each enclosing `</script>` tag followed by a new line (for readability)?

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation of html-webpack-plugin [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/tree/v3.2.0) you can pass options to the [html-minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference) used by the plugin.

This allows you to skip white space removal using `collapseWhitespace: false` option. So if you're initial template includes new lines they would be preserved.

This won't be enough since the injected script tags already have no white spaces in between.

So, in addition to we would need to also:

1. Stop the plugin from injecting the script tags by using `inject: false` option.
2. Use the template to inject the script tags ourselves providing the new lines we need.

The config would then be:

```js
new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  template: "src/index.ejs",
  filename: "index.html",
  inject:   false,
  minify: { collapseWhitespace: false }
})
```

And the template `scr/index.ejs` would be something like:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>Some content</div><%
  for (const tag of htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.bodyTags) { %>
    <%= tag %><%
  } %>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output then would be something like:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <script src="vendors~main.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: adding `minify: { collapseWhitespace: false }` didn't affect my issue

Comment: @Mr. Thanks for your feedback. I'm sorry, it seems I did not fully understand the issue at first. Please review my updated answer. Thanks!

Comment: thank you for the update! didn't test it yet, but rather than supporting each builtin functionality of the plugin in the template, i wanted to take advantage of the  `inject: body` functionality... :|

Comment: @Mr. I get  your point. But, currently there seems to be no other way. Also, you're already using a template so the only built-in functionality that was available and we're overriding is the injection of the tags, which was simply based on regular expressions to decide on the location of injection.