# Prevent HtmlWebpackPlugin from minimizing line breaks in production

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-production

Here is the relevant part of my webpack config:

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      hash: false, // for testing purposes
      minify: false,
    }),    
  ]
```

Despite `minify: false`, HTML becomes one line if `mode: 'production'`. If `mode: 'development'`, then it's multiple lines. If I change `hash: true`, then it becomes one line with query string hashes for cache busting, which proves that it reads this configuration object.

But why does it truncate line breaks? I tried to [specify an object](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#minification) and set `collapseWhitespace` and other props instead of `minify: false`, but it also had no effect, still made it one line. Here is a list of versions from package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate": "^0.10.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.3.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "1.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.4",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "5.39.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
```

**EDIT:** To clarify, I am referring to truncation of line breaks between the dynamic includes inserted by webpack, which are references to bundled JS and CSS file. All these files appear in exactly one line, no matter if it's production or development build. It seems there is no way to split them line by line, as if they were carefully inserted by a human.

Why is it useful to see each dynamic include in its own line? For example if you want to check the order. Currently the only option is to scroll left/right and try to memorize what appears off screen, which is more cognitive load then reading a list top to bottom, where everything fits on one screen without scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you are using **html-loader**. My guess is that it's not the **HtmlWebpackPlugin** that is doing the minification in your case since you set `minify: false`, but **html-loader**.

In order to stop **html-loader** from minifying we can set something like this:

```
test: /\.html$/,
use: {
  loader: "html-loader",
  options: {
    minimize: false,
  },
}
```

However, since you also want to have the **.js** and **.css** includes in the generated **.html** file on separate lines we run into a problem. The reason they are on the same line is because they are injected by **HtmlWebpackPlugin** without any line breaks in the first place. As far as I know there is no option for this that we could set.

## Solution 1

### Step 1

The best solution that I've found is to create our template file using **EJS** (https://ejs.co/) instead of plain html. This allows us to write javascript directly into the template and gives us complete control over how the includes are injected. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62992909) answer.

Start by renaming your html template file to something like **template.ejs**. Next add this right before the closing `</head>` tag:

```
for (const tag of htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.headTags) { %>
  <%= tag %><%
} %>
```

Make sure not to have auto-format enabled since we rely on the line breaks here to generate the correct output format. Depending on what version of **HtmlWebpackPlugin** you are using you might also use **bodyTags** in addition to **headTags**. It seems to me that at least in latest version they have chosen to put **script** includes in the head with a **defer** flag in order to delay execution, which is also the most performant way of doing it as far as I understand it.

### Step 2

Next we need change the path of the template in the **HtmlWebpackPlugin** options, and also disable the auto injection of includes like so:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: "./src/template.ejs",
  inject: false
}),
```

### Step 3

Since **HtmlWebpackPlugin** has a built in fallback **.ejs** parser we don't need to install any extra loader for that. The only problem is that since you are using the **html-loader** I assume you have assets in your template file like images etc. If you were to create a new rule that would test for **.ejs** files and use **html-loader** to process them it would indeed work to replace hard coded **src** includes with dynamic ones as is the purpose of the loader. However, specifying a loader for **.ejs** files would stop **HtmlWebpackPlugin** from using it's fallback parser and thus all the template variables (those inside `<% %>`) to be left unparsed.

However we actually don't need **html-loader** at all. Instead what you can do is to use **EJS** to **require** your assets in the template file like so:

```
<img src="<%= require('./assets/myimage.jpg') %>" />
```

## Solution 2

In case for some reason you need / prefer to use the **html-loader** instead there is another way to go about the issue.

Since **HtmlWebpackPlugin** won't use it's fallback EJS parser when **html-loader** is activated we need to parse it using another loader, called **ejs-loader**. There is a slight issue though: when **html-loader** parses the template file it generates **javascript**. Since **ejs-loader** don't expect to receive javascript we need to first convert it back to EJS format. This can be done by yet another loader called **extract-loader**.

Start by following **Step 1** from **Solution 1**. Next we need to install the two new loaders:

```
yarn add -D ejs-loader extract-loader
```

After that we add them to the **module rules** in the **webpack config**. Make sure to set **esModule** to **false** also for the **html-loader** since extract-loader can't handle that:

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.ejs$/,
    use: [
    {
      loader: "ejs-loader",
      options: {
        esModule: false
      }
      },
      'extract-loader',
      {
      loader: "html-loader",
      options: {
        esModule: false
      },
    }]
  },

  ...
```

This setup starts with **html-loader** that automatically parses any **src** includes and converts it to **require** statements. It generates **javascript** code that **extract-loader** converts back to **EJS**. Finally **ejs-loader** parses the **template variables**, in this case the list of **js** / **css** includes.

Comment: It's a good answer, but it doesn't solve my problem, because all dynamic JS/CSS includes are still in one line. All the rest is split into multiple lines like the original, so I'll upvote. But I cannot accept because it does not solve the problem completely. Also one can achieve same behavior by switching webpack to dev mode.

Comment: @Neolisk I've updated the answer to also address .js files.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Dev setup does not minify JS by default. But it still puts all JS and CSS imports in one line **in HTML**.

Comment: @Neolisk Alright, I misunderstood. I've now updated the answer with a solution to that problem. I think you should also edit your original question since it's not clear that you are also looking for a way to control the injection of js/css includes.

Comment: I need html-loader to deal with AngularJS templates which are scattered across the application, hundreds of them. Webpack needs to replace all mentions of static resources with a content hashed version. It's not just a single html file. It's not feasible to convert hundreds of htmls spanning 50k LOC into ejs. I now realize that having all dynamic includes as one line in the output html is a relatively minor issue. Especially considering the effort and trade offs you outlined above.

Comment: @Neolisk Ok, in that case I understand that it's not so simple going the 100% ejs path. I've added an alternate approach that I think might work for you.

Comment: But how do I go without ES modules? That was one of the selling points in this webpack conversion, no longer having to think about polluting the global scope, no need for IIFE. Code scoping is essential for enterprise development.

Comment: @Neolisk You can use ES modules, no problem. The setting to turn them off is just affecting HTML loader so that it converts your template file to javascript utilizing 'require' instead of 'import'. This is necessary in order for exctract-loader to parse the data in the next step.

Comment: Ok, I will accept your answer then. Thanks.